# PHP array not outputting properly

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to do form validation but when I try to print out the contents of an array when there is an error it doesnt output anything.

```
$errors = array();

if (strlen($password) >= 6) {
    array_push($errors, "Your password is not long enough! Must be over 6 characters!");
}

if(count($errors) !== 0) { 
...
} else {
    echo "There is errors<br/>"; 
    foreach($errors as $er){
        echo $er . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

What I do get is "There is errors" so I know that the if else is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have to correct the argument of the `if`:

```
if(count($errors) === 0) {
     // everything is okay
} else {
    echo "There are errors<br/>"; 
    foreach($errors as $er){
        echo $er . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

In this way, when your error count **is** 0, the content of the `if` is executed. When it isn't 0, the content of the `else` is executed and the errors are printed. It's just the opposite of what you did. 
(I also corrected the sentence: it's ‘there are errors’, not ‘there is errors’ :P)

Furthermore, the other `if` is wrong as well, it should be the opposite:

```
if (strlen($password) <= 6) {
```

since you need to check when the password is **less** than 6 characters.

Comment: Further, you don't even need the `count($errors)`, as an empty array will evaluate to `FALSE`. You can do `if($errors) { echo 'there are errors'; }`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (strlen($password) < 6) {
  array_push($errors, ...);
```

?

BTW you should use at least constants instead of [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants), e.g.

```
define('MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH', 6);

// ...

if (strlen($password) < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
    array_push($errors, "Your password is not long enough!"
      . " Must be over ".MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH." characters!");
}
```

This way, if your minimal required length changes, you just have to change it once.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is messed up.  You are checking for errors, then doing nothing, then the else is where it is displaying the errors.  Try this:

```
if(count($errors) >0) {  //there are errors 
    echo "There is errors<br/>"; 
    foreach($errors as $er){
        echo $er . "<br/>";
    }
}else{
    //there are no errors
}
```

Also, your password length should be `<=6` not greater than or equal to if it is too short.